# Wait for all promises and start a function (image caching before rendering)

Tags: javascript, promise

The goal is to create an image cache preloaded images, to use them without updating while function init. So to prepare images for a further usage.
Currently I've got this code:

```js
var links = [
  'https://get.wallhere.com/photo/trees-forest-fall-waterfall-water-nature-rocks-national-park-pond-jungle-stream-rainforest-watercourse-wasserfall-habitat-natural-environment-body-of-water-water-feature-57484.jpg',
  'http://ru.artsdot.com/ADC/Photos-ImgScreen.nsf/O/P-AC6V56/$FILE/Buildings-night_city_65_.Jpg',
  'https://cdn.wallaps.com/wallpapers/10000/2870.jpg',
  'http://on-desktop.com/wps/Nature_Beach_Bright_paints_of_coast_023115_.jpg',
  'http://wallpaperscraft.ru/image/ravnina_zelen_solnce_gory_derevya_trava_326_2560x1600.jpg'
];
const checkImage = (path) => {
 const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
  const img = new Image();
  
  img.onload = () => resolve({path, status: 'ok'});
  img.src = path
 })
 promise.then(result => console.log('...image loaded'))
}
 
const loadImg = (paths) => Promise.all(paths.map(checkImage)).then(result => console.log('here we start a function'));
loadImg(links)
```

But ".then(here we start a function)" starts before any of promises is ready? What am I missing in logic to solve this issue?

Comment: Your not returning your promise in checkImage.. just put  `return promise;` at the end of checkImage function.

Comment: The thing about `Promise.all` is .. if any of the items in the array are not Promises, they are converted to Promises - that way, you can have a mixture of Promise/Non-Promise ... as the first comment states, your checkImage function has no return statement ... ie. it returns `undefined`

Comment: Damn, right! So the .all in my case wasnt getting promises... Thanks for clues! Please, make the answer so I can accept it.

Comment: The image may never load, you can do `img.onerror = reject;` but you may want to catch rejecting image load promises: `Promise.all(paths.map(path=>checkImage(path).catch(x=>x)))`

Comment: @HMR, the most ununderstandable thing for me now, is when I preload the images, the next function which updates html with these images, sometimes load them from server again: http://prntscr.com/hq0jbx . And all these promises to undertand is it possible via frontend preload all images to manipulate them from cache.

Comment: Don't forget `img.onerror = reject;` otherwise any single promise may hang, causing  `Promise.all()` to hang. Also remember to catch that rejection.